# .htaccess URL rewrite not working at all

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

So I have a .haccess file which is meant to rewrite the URL `profile.php?user_username=Test`to be `keepkey.96.it/test` but it does not work. The URL 
remains the same.

Here's my .htaccess file

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+profile\.php\?user_username=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ profile.php?user_username=$1 [L]
```

---

EDIT: I've managed to get the URL to rewrite, it now shows as `http://keepkey.96.lt/Test` instead of `http://keepkey.96.lt/profile.php?user_username=Test`. But now I get an `error 404` message, any ideas why?

Here's the error message:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /Test was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: Make sure whether your .htaccess file located in the right directory, and make sure that no other .htaccess files are being executed before yours.

Comment: It would be silly to point, but did you enable mod_rewrite module in Apache/tomcat?

Comment: I'm using a host, and according to their response http://www.hostinger.ph/knowledge-base/99.html mod_rewrite is enabled by default on our servers.[/link]

Comment: At this point the second rule seems doing the other way around... Like if /test is being the input it's creating user-profile.php?user-name=test as the target URL... Are you sure it was working before? If not just try shifting left to right. Sorry am not that good at REGex ..

Comment: @PravyNandas No, the code didn't seem to work at all in the beginning, what do you mean by try shifting left to right? (Sorry, complete amateur here)

Comment: Something like RewriteRule    ^user-profile\.php\?user_username=(.*)$  /$1 [L]

Comment: Nope, that didn't seem to work. It appears that the `.htaccess` file is not working at all. This is really frustrating!

Comment: Good that you are at least getting redirect now. Your requested URL says Test1 and target URL says Test, check if you have a folder Test and an index.php file in it.

Comment: @PravyNandas Nope, there shouldn't be a folder as `Test` should be the Username of the user. Not a directory.